# Compare a string with an ArrayList string element

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I need some help to fix my issue as I described below:

I have an array list with name datalist and it has elements like ah3w   38 45 1, zj4e 32 4 45. I want to compare a string like ah3w 38 45 1 for checking is it in arraylist or not. The main problem is whitespaces. I want to ignore them because sometimes I have elements in arraylist which has more than one white space between characters. I had tried something like below with using replaceAll method, but it didnt work. Lastly I tried to remove all white space before I created the arraylist, then I did same thing for my string too, it worked but it is not like I want. I dont want to change anything I just want to compare them without spaces. Here is my code example:

```
String field = "ah3w 38 45 1"
for(int a=0; a<datalist.size(); a++){
   if(datalist.get(a).replaceAll("\\s+","").contains(field.replaceAll("\\s+",""))){
      datalist.remove(a);
   }
}
```

Here is another code block that is doing same thing and you can run and see what I am trying to do and what ı am getting:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReplaceAllElementsOfArrayListExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    String field= "ah3w 38 45 1";

    arrayList.add("zj4e 32   4  45");
    arrayList.add("ah3w       38  45   1");
    arrayList.add("ab2 56 2 45");

    System.out.println("Before replacement, ArrayList contains : " + arrayList);

    if(arrayList.get(1).replaceAll("\\s+","").contains(field.replaceAll("\\s+",""))){

    System.out.println("They are equal : " + arrayList);}
    else{
      System.out.println("They are not equal : " + arrayList);  
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried trim() before but it didnt work.

Comment: I had filled my array list like get the data one by one and add the list like below: data.trim(); datalist.add(data);

Comment: “sometimes I have elements in arraylist which has more than one white space between characters”. `trim()` doesn’t modify such occurrences of more than one space between other characters, so you can leave that out of your consideration.

Comment: Does `String.trim()` remove all whitespaces? Thought trim function only removes whitespaces in front and in the end of the string, not between. Your `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` works fine for me to remove all whitespaces, but `replaceAll(" ", "")` will give you the same result.

Comment: I thought replaceAll will work but I think it doesnt work for arrays. If you compare two string it works fine but not same for anoe string and one array list element

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code in the question works nicely for me. I feed it `datalist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("ah3w 38 45 1", "zj4e 32 4 45", "ah3w  38  45  1"));` and get `[zj4e 32 4 45]` out. What more could you wish for? ;-) Notice in the last string I have two spaces rather than one between the alphanumeric elements, Stack Overflow may not show that.

Comment: You don't call `replaceAll` on an array in your example. Please update your example if you want us to help you.

Comment: Indeed there are two calls to `replaceAll()` in the code in the question. The first one is on an element from the array list, `datalist.get(a)` (taking `datalist` to be an array list).

Comment: Consider whether you want to consider "ah3w 38 45 1" and "ah3w 3 84 51" equal. If not, replace runs of whitespace with a single space rather than the empty string.

Comment: the arraylist is "ah3w 38 45 1", "zj4e 32 4 45", "ah3w 38 45 1" . And my string is "ah3w 38 45 1". I called replaceAll method in my if check.

Comment: am trying to say, the space that are between characters may be different. in my example I am trying to enteer 2 space but it looks like one space between ah3w and 38

Comment: Oscar Sayin, it sounds like you and I are trying the same thing. Are you getting the same result as I reported in a previous comment?

Comment: Hi Ole, I added an other code block you can execute and see what I am getting and what is the problem.

Comment: Your new code doesn’t compile as it stands. For `get(1).replaceAll()` to work you should use a type argument to `ArrayList`: `ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`. With this change your program prints: Before replacement, ArrayList contains : [zj4e 32   4  45, ah3w       38  45   1, ab2 56 2 45]
They are equal : [zj4e 32   4  45, ah3w       38  45   1, ab2 56 2 45]

Comment: PS I just saw your new comment and your edit now. If you type @OleVV somewhere in your comment, I will be notified as soon as I go to Stack Overflow.

Comment: So it seems the problem was that you were using raw types all the time? It’s the same in your original code, this expression: `datalist.get(a).replaceAll("\\s+","")`. If `datalist` is a raw `ArrayList` it cannot be compiled. With `ArrayList<String>` it can.

Comment: Takeaways are: (1) On Stack Overflow post a complete example like you did the second time, not just the lines where you think the problem is. (2) Don’t just say “it didnt work”. Give exact output and exact error message, and I think we can help you much faster. (3) Nearly nobody uses raw (non-generic) collection types (like ArrayList) these days. They tend to give errors that are hard to track down. You too, stop doing that. (4) Listen to your compiler warnings. I have set mine up to warn me is I forget type arguments.

Comment: Thanks Ole for your advices. I will do as you said for next time if I have question. I am new on stackoverflow and also in java. So I appriciate for your helps and advices again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String field = "ah3w 38 45 1";

        arrayList.add("zj4e 32   4  45");
        arrayList.add("ah3w       38  45   1");
        arrayList.add("ab2 56 2 45");

        //solution
        String fieldNoWhitespaces = field.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        for (String dataElement : arrayList) {
            String arg = dataElement.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            if (fieldNoWhitespaces.equals(arg)) arrayList.remove(dataElement);      
        }
        
        //just to check for correctness
        for (String dataElement : arrayList) {
            System.out.println(":::" + dataElement);

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataElement.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(dataElement.charAt(i))) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

        System.out.println(":::Whitespaces:::" + count);
    }
```

Output:

> :::zj4e 32   4  45
>
> :::Whitespaces:::6
>
> :::ab2 56 2 45
>
> :::Whitespaces:::3

Comment: Thanks for answer I tried this code part and it works. But when I apply same logic in my code I am gettin this error. Do you have any idea about it? **     incompatible types
    [javac] found   : java.lang.Object
    [javac] required: java.lang.String
    [javac]         for (String dataElement : cmlist) {**

Comment: By the way I have java.lang.* library on the top of my code

Comment: Please be aware that I changed a line of your code from ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(); to ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); thus I say the arrayList contains Strings. And since the for loop says, that each element from the list cmlist is from type String, you have to explicitly tell the arrayList that the values are Strings.

Comment: if my post answers your question, it would be nice if you could mark it as the answer :)